# Setting single pixel of BufferedImage sets the same pixel in another BufferedImage. Why?

Tags: java, memory, bufferedimage, behavior

I came across this issue when programming another project, but I have simplified the code down to what suffers directly from said issue.

EntryPoint.java

```
package replaced.with.real.package.in.code.at.compile.time;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

public class EntryPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage a = new BufferedImage(1024, 768, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(1024, 768, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        a = Util.genOriginBlue();
        b = Util.genOriginBlue();
        a.setRGB(new Random(0L).nextInt(500), new Random(1L).nextInt(500), 0xffffff);
        System.out.println(a == b);
    }

}
```

Util.java

```
package replaced.with.real.package.in.code.at.compile.time;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class Util
{
    static BufferedImage oB;

    public static BufferedImage genOriginBlue()
    {
        if(oB == null)
        {
            oB = new BufferedImage(1024, 768, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            oB.setRGB(0, 0, 1, 1, new int[] {255}, 0, 1);
        }
        return oB;
    }
}
```

This prints 'true', indicating that BufferedImage a and BufferedImage b are the same. Seen as I generated them in the same way until the line beginning 'a.setRG(....' that makes BufferedImage a different, I would not expect that output. This becomes worse if I start looping code like this, but especially code that generates output BufferedImage a differently each time, which is exactly what I do in the aforementioned project.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

On a separate note, this is the second question I have posted here ever, so please, speak out if I am not doing it right.

Cheers.

Comment: Try `.equals()` in that first one.

Comment: @BitNinja having tested that, it produces the same output.
That is, if you are referring to 'System.out.println(a == b);' and suggesting that it should be 'System.out.println(a.equals(b));'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    BufferedImage a = new BufferedImage(1024, 768, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(1024, 768, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

The above lines of code do nothing since in the following two lines of code you reset the values of the "a" and "b" variables to the value returned from the Util.GenOriginBlue() method.

```
    a = Util.genOriginBlue();
    b = Util.genOriginBlue();
```

In your Util class you then use:

```
static BufferedImage oB;
```

This means that you will only ever have a single instance of the BufferedImage. So the if statement in your code will only be executed once, and then the second time the method is invoked you just return the same reference to the BufferedImage.

You need to create a new instance of the BufferedImage in the Util.genOriginBlue() method. So get rid of the static "ob" variable and get rid of the if statement. Then your BufferedImage will be the same when you create it, but you will be able to change the pixels separately.

Comment: I appreciate the help, this solved part of the problem. The second part remains: In my bigger project, that uses segments of code like these, I do more advanced things than setting a single pixel. For example, drawing some advanced 2D geometry. I do this, the same way, 50 times/sec. Said items of geometry, all up, take a while to render on a not-so-beefy computer, and I really only want to do such a task once in a program's execution, as opposed to frequently. In the latter case, I would end up doing the same, resource-intensive thing, repeatedly. Thanks in advance to anyone seeking the tick.